# How gmail maintaining open Connections?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap

I have a doubt regarding Gmail Open connection. Gmail saying that, maximum Open connection is 15 per account. But i Logged in from different system with different browsers. currently 20 places the particular accounts is open... so nothing happened. when accessing from IMAP, it is restricting to 15 connections. Does google following different approach when login from Web and When login from IMAP?. please clarify this....

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got answer for my question....

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/97150?hl=en

This above link explained me what i want.